# How do you manage the events in a UINavigationController view to switch views?

Tags: xcode, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController w/ three views and associated buttons in the UINavigationBar for each view. Since I am new to XCode I'm trying to understand where to put the event handling code for managing the switch between views.

View A (root)

Goto View B (button)

View B

Back (button)   Gotto View C (button)

View C

Back (button)

I see how to capture the event when "Goto View B" is clicked, but since that button is created in View A it does not have access to the UINavigationController to switch views.

Any samples or links to additional info appreciated.

Comment: See new related question w/ detailed code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598571/how-do-i-structure-the-uinavigation-controller-and-associated-view-controllers-fo.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, have a look at:

UINavigationControllerDelegate: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

UINavigationBarDelegate: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

If you are simply trying to push a new view using the navigationController, it is as simple as this (in your `GoToViewB` button/action):

```
YourNewViewController *yourNewViewController = [[YourNewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourNewViewController animated:YES];
[yourNewViewController release];
```

Now you should be in your newViewController, which will have a back button to return to the previous view. You can use the same logic as above to go to the next view etc. If you want to pop a controller programatically, you can use:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: The problem is self.navigationController is not in scope in the view controller where the button and it's event handler are located. I understand the manipulation of views w/in the navigation controller, it's just the navigation controller is one level higher in the object hierarchy than the view that contains the button and handler.

Comment: where is your navController in relation to view A, B and C?

Comment: see comment above in question for link to new question w/ detailed code.